# Plaid Webhook Ach stripe payment update issue

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, payment, plaid

I'm integrating plaid in node with stripe integration.I have created stripe token and with token created stripe customers successfully using plaid.

- Now i have created a stripe charge request with created customer successfully. i have received stripe transaction response with "pending" status.
- I have created a plaid webhook url and i have also received a webhook response when i was created customer using plaid so that show webhook url is working.
- Issue is that how i get generated transaction status is updated or completed from webhook.
  please help me i'm stucked. i'm not able to update my transaction status in database.

Answer (score 1):

When you say transaction, I’m assuming you’re referring to the Stripe charge and a Stripe webhook endpoint, but if this isn’t what you meant, let me know. Since you have confirmed that your webhook is working and is receiving events, I believe the problem is that there just hasn’t been enough time for the `charge.succeeded` or `charge.failed` events to have been triggered. Those events come up to 5 days after you get the `charge.pending` event: https://stripe.com/docs/ach#ach-specific-webhook-notifications.